# Implement a function that would read a sequence of values from an input stream as an argument

Tags: c++, stream

In a problem I was given to try in a C++ book I was told to make a function that would take an input stream as an argument with values being an int stored in a sequence in the stream.

Now I'd get the declaration would be something like:

```
foo(istream &arg);
```

But I can't seem to understand how I would get the values inside the input stream and store it in another variable. Could somebody help me out and give me a simple example I could understand?

Thank you.

Comment: [`istream`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/)'s `>>` operator may be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you don't understand.  To read a single value, you
use the `>>` operator on the stream.  To read more than one value, you
use `>>` more than once; if you want to read the entire stream, you loop
until the input fails.  To store the values, you use `std::vector<int>`,
using `push_back` to insert each value.

Of course, an experienced C++ programmer is more likely to use an 
`std::istream_iterator<int>` to directly initialize the vector:

```
std::vector<int>
foo( std::istream& inputStream )
{
    return std::vector<int>
        (std::istream_iterator<int>( inputStream )),
        (std::istream_iterator<int>()) );
}
```

The purpose of the problem, however, seems to be learning how to write a
loop, so for learning purposes, you should probably write your own loop.

Answer (score 0):

Streams use the stream operators, e.g.:

```
std::cout << "enter an integer number: ";
```

and

```
int x;
std::cin >> x;
```

Since this looks like homework, I'll leave it at this hint.

As you'd guess `std::cin` is an example of an `istream` (input stream), and `std::cout` is an `ostream` (output stream)

Comment: See, this part of the problem isn't giving me a hard time. My question is once I get a referenced stream that has multiple values, how can I grab each one individually. I know I could do arg >> x >> y >> z but I want to do something along the lines of arg >> x and just keep grabbing values from arg to x and looping when there's nothing left in the arg stream.

Comment: `while (std::cin >> x) { /*do stuff?*/ }` (for the record, your question _did say_ 'how I would get the values inside the input stream'?!)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to keep the values given within your `istream`, or just junk them (like waiting for the user to hit the ENTER key before continuing to another portion of the program)?

You may want [std::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) which will read in everything to the next newline, and store the entire chunk into a string that you can parse (or discard).

As mentioned, the `>>` will read in another value (usually whitespace delimited) one-by-one, so you can store the first input into variable `x`, the second into `y`, the third into `z`, etc.  (If you want to get really fancy, you can even push them into a `vector`, `list`, `deque`, or any other container type of your choosing.)